# Creating a HtmlHelper to display content if certain conditions are fulfilled

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to create a simple HtmlHelper to that I can use like this:

```
@using(Html.DisplayIf(Object object))
{
...
}
```

I tried the method suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8292497/how-can-i-create-a-html-helper-like-html-beginform), but unlike the guy who asked that question I would like the content between the brackets not to be rendered at all, not just hidden.

Is there a way to prevent the textwriter from writing the content between the brackets, or some other method that would be appropriate to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited**

You can use the method described here: [Capture wrapped content in BeginForm style disposable html helper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013095/capture-wrapped-content-in-beginform-style-disposable-html-helper).
I've applied the first method to your example.

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    public static HelperResult DisplayIf(this HtmlHelper html, Func<object, HelperResult> template, bool show)
    {
        return new HelperResult(writer =>
        {
            if (show)
            {
                template(null).WriteTo(writer);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
@* Will render *@
@Html.DisplayIf(
    @<span>test1</span>, true
)
@* Will not render *@
@Html.DisplayIf(
    @<span>test2</span>, false
)
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me, the content is still written two the TextWriter

Comment: What does the object parameter contain? And what kind of check has to be performed to output the content?

Comment: What about `DisplayIf(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool show)`?

Comment: public static IDisposable DisplaySkjermet(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper, bool show)
        {                 
            return new RoleContainer(null);
        }

Comment: Even this doesn't prevent the content from rendering

Comment: You are right, the content for an IDisposable helper always renders. Here is a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013095/capture-wrapped-content-in-beginform-style-disposable-html-helper
I've updated my answer.